# Marking a bucket as removed in Hash Table

Tags: c++, hashtable, linear-probing

I have been having some trouble finding a decent explanation on this. I am writing a linear probing hash table using C++, but I am having trouble with the `remove()` operation. I am hashing a dictionary collection of `strings`, and I am wondering how I would set the index `i` remove from as deleted, so the `search()` and `insert()` work properly. Any help/pseudocode would be great, thank you. My best guess right now, is to make some sort of struct object called `deleted` and place it there.

Comment: Maybe each bucket has a `bool` flag?

Comment: i thought of this....but how would you implement each bucket as contatining a bool on creation?

Answer (score 0):

Each bucket could be a `struct` containing the key, value and a flag to indicate if the bucket is empty like this:

```
struct bucket
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    bool empty = true;
};
```

Then you could have a `std::vector` of such buckets:

```
class hash_table
{
public:
    hash_table(): buckets(100) {} // hash table has 100 buckets

    void put(std::string const& key, std::string const& value)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // etc...

private:
    std::vector<bucket> buckets; // the table
};
```